# Why we need constructor in C++, we can do same thing by help of functions( either initialization of data or accessing the private data members )

Tags: c++, constructor

Kindly give the answer with an perfect example.
In the Below program why we need constructor whereas we can do the same thing by function.
(supposing that we are passing some values through main() )

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class name {
private:
int roll_num;
char grade;
public:
void set_roll(int data);      /* function to get the values of roll num and grade */
void set_grade(char grade_1);
void display(void);
.
.
name(int ..., char ....)      /* constructor for the same thing as function doing */
```

Comment: Why do we need classes? We could do the same with functions. Why do we need functions? We could do the same with copy/paste.

Comment: Well just use `c` and you don't have to worry about these pesky constructors and destructors...

Comment: No, actually you can't perform initialization of data outside the constructor.  You can only perform assignment.  Quite different for some types (classic example: ALL references).

Comment: You really do like asking questions about constructors, eh? Maybe it would help to read some tutorials or books about the topic to clear up some confusion.

Comment: A constructor *is* a function.

Comment: One reason is constructor will be called automatically and so will be the destructor. normal function will not be called automatically.

second reason is to allocate and disallocate memory automatically.

It greatly helps the programmer, since he does not to have to call the constructor and destructor.

Third reason is initalization must be done when obeject is created. If function is assigned to this task, it will behave same way. but the programmer may forget to not initialize in some case, which may cause the problem

Comment: Constructors tie together object *creation* and object *initialisation*. As well as making user code more compact, they prevent the mistake of creating an object but forgetting to initialise it.

Answer (score 5):

Some members need to be set on initialization, if you want to set a class's constant member it has to be done in the constructor for example:

```
class A{
    const int a;
    A(int b):a(b){}
};
```

Comment: Right, the original question is conflating *initialization* with *assignment*.

Answer (score 2):

Constructors allow you to treat class-type objects as opaque values, without requiring knowledge or maintenance of their interna.

Consider this example:

```
std::vector<std::string> v;

void save(std::string s)
{
    v.push_back(std::move(s));
}
```

We can call this function as `save("Hello world")`, and we can treat the argument as an opaque *value*. This is because the class `std::string` has constructors that perform the necessary operations to create the internal state and to transfer the state to an element in the vector. The user never needs to know about this and is not responsible for keeping the internal states consistent.

Objects are more than just their state. They also define ways of modifying the state. Constructors are a fundamental part of that.

Answer (score 1):

A constructor prepares the new object upon creation.  It can be used to set variables to default values, or user-input parameters.

Using a function to say, set a variable value, would require additional steps.  This can be done during object creation by including parameter values.